# How to move linux from thumb drive to internal drive?

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk

I have latest version of Linux Mint Cinnamon (persistent data) in 16 GB thumb drive and I want to move it to internal hard drive which is 128 GB.

How do I do that and do I lose 112 GB or can it make 16 GB image to fill entire drive so I have 128 GB of space?

Comment: This is something the Mint manuals (or their specialized fora) can answer much better than we here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to copy it instead of installing and just copying your personal data, but the procedure to replicate a system would be (if you follow the next procedure you will be able to use your HD's full capacity):

> 1. Recreate filesystems: run `fdisk -l /dev/your_usb_device` and
>      recreate those in your HD (you can modify sizes and have more
>      partitions if you have some special distribution in mind, but those
>      on the usb must exist in your new device and have at least the same size). Use `fdisk` to partition your HD.
> 2. Create those filesystems: run `mkfs` and `mkswap` to create the
>      needed filesystems.
> 3. Mount your HD's root in /mnt (if you have extra partitions for
>      /home, /var ... you should mount them under /mnt): `mount /dev/your_HD /mnt`
> 4. Copy files from USB to HD: `rsync -av --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys
>      --exclude=/proc --exclude=/mnt /* /mnt/`
> 5. Identify your devices' IDs: `blkid` will give you the IDs, find
>      those of your HD's new partitions and modify `/mnt/etc/fstab` so that
>      the mount IDs match the new ones.
> 6. Modify `grub.cfg`: Modify your `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so that it
>      points to the new HD ID's.
> 7. Install GRUB in your HD's MBR: `grub-install
>      --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/your_HD`

After that you should be able to start from your HD (you won't need the USB key when booting).

I hope I haven't missed any step (I'm writing these steps as I remember them) but in case of problems let me know.

If you're using uefi you may need some extra configuration and/or parameters in grub-install.